# Kotlin - java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null

Tags: api, kotlin

Guys how can I fix the error java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null

```
experiments.forEach {
    if(NAME_VARIANT == it.variantName) {
        for (i in (0..Math.min(result.size - 1, Constants.MAX_METHODS_APPLIED))) {
            if (response.paymentMethods[i].scoring.rules!!.none { it.ruleName == NAME_RULE}) {
                response.appliedExperiments.clear()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more logs.

Comment: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1043) ~[?:?]
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:997) ~[?:?]
 at com.ex.model.sorting.SortingModel.apply(SortingModel.kt:101) ~[main/:?]

Comment: Could it be that `experiments` here is the same list as `response.appliedExperiments`?

Comment: yes, I build response.appliedExperiments from experiments

Comment: Please show the code that creates `response.appliedExperiments` from `experiments` - you need to make sure it's a new list. It can contain the same elements but it cannot be the *same* list.

Comment: `val response = SortingServiceResponse(experiments, result)`

`data class SortingServiceResponse(
    val appliedExperiments: MutableList<ListInfo>,
    val listMethods: List<SortingServiceResponse>
)`

Answer (score 0):

This exception `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown when you're trying to modify a collection at the same time as iterating over it.

In the piece of code you provided, you're iterating over `experiments`, and you're modifying `response.appliedExperiments` (by calling `clear()` on it). If those 2 variables actually point to the same collection, calling `clear()` is expected to throw.

In order to do what you want, you probably want those lists to start off as copies of each other, but still be different. When you create `response.appliedExperiments`, make sure it's a new list and not the same list.

EDIT: in the code you provided, you are passing `experiments` directly to the constructor of `SortingServiceResponse`, and I'm guessing this constructor uses the list as-is as the `appliedExperiments` property of `reponse`. Instead, you should pass a copy of the list, for instance using `toMutableList()`:

```kotlin
val response = SortingServiceResponse(experiments.toMutableList(), result)
```

An even better approach would be to use read-only `List` instead of `MutableList` for `experiments` to avoid making this kind of mistakes in the first place. Only use mutable collections when you really need to. Most of the time, you can use operators (like `filter` or `map`) that create new read-only lists instead of working with mutable lists directly.

Comment: What would be the best way to do it then?

Comment: I edited my answer based on your addiitonal info in the comments